# Is it possible to open a US bank account without being physically present or having a SSN/EIN?

Tags: united-states, bank-account, international, non-resident

I want open business bank account in Michigan. I have not SSN. I have EIN. My friend is in Michigan. I don't want to go USA just for open Bank account. Is this possible to open business account online without physical present in USA?

Comment: "Which is best" is a Shopping Question and out of scope for SE. "Is it possible" should be OK if someone knows. Have you checked past answers to similar questions?